# Find the arc length of $r=\sin(3\theta)$

Tags: calculus

I'm having a hard time finding the arc length of one section of the polar equation $r=\sin(3\theta)$.

I thought I had a good understanding but the integration seems to be a nightmare. Unless I'm not doing something correctly.

Comment: If I'm correct, I believe it's the integration of (8cos^2(3theta)+1)^1/2

Comment: Yes, you're correct, and that integral does not have a closed form in terms of simple functions. [Here's](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate+Sqrt%5B+1+%2B+8+Cos%5B3x%5D%5E2+%5D) what Wolfram|Alpha gave me. Are you supposed to actually do the integral or just to derive a representation of the arc length (in which case leaving the integral unevaluated is fine) ?

Comment: Thank you, I thought I was doing something completely wrong. I was expecting it to be a contrived problem. The Wolfram link worked perfect, it had the  definite integral I needed. Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome but the best way to thank me is to give back to the community by writing - as an answer - your solution to the question you asked. That way, when others happen to land on this page, they'll see an answer to the question, and not just the question. You can also accept it yourself. Just make sure that it's correct, clear, and well-written. Win-win for everyone!

Comment: You'll probably need [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) if you're going to post an answer.

Comment: Very well written @wltrup. People like you make this site better

Comment: @Shailesh Thanks. I hope that by repeating that comment whenever it's appropriate, people might start to actually do it. So far, 50% success.

Comment: Hope I can use your comment elsewhere without paying royalty